# In Access 2007 VBA, can unsaved forms and reports be typed as 'AccessObject'..?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm in Access 2007 VBA, creating code which is used to automate the layout & formatting of controls on forms & reports in design view.

In order to streamline my code, I'm trying to reference forms and reports as a common root type, so a single variable "thisDoc" can reference them. I thought that would be "AccessObject", but it seems not. I get runtime error #13, type mismatch.

Do forms and reports have a common root type..? If so, what is it..?

The type "Object" is certainly possible, but I would prefer something closer to the children in the Access object hierarchy. This is to avoid late-binding, and to satisfy my OCD, but mostly to have IntelliSense work properly.

Here's the problem: my code accesses the active form or report currently on screen, which may not yet be saved. As such, they do not yet appear in AllForms or AllReports. And in the case of dynamic forms/reports, they never will.

Here is example code that encapsulates the issue:

```
dim app      as Access.Application
dim scr      as Access.Screen
dim thisDoc  as Access.AccessObject 'but "As Object" works ok.
set app       = Access.Application
set scr       = app.Screen
set thisDoc   = scr.ActiveReport     'or .ActiveForm       
'Runtime error #13: Type Mismatch.
```

As noted, the vartype "Object" works, but as I mentioned above, I'd like to at least get a type that's in the Access object hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's no common interface between the `Report` and the `Form` object (except for `Object`, of course, which can be used for any object.

The `AccessObject` interface is *not* used for forms and reports like you normally use them. You can't access things like controls through it. It's mainly used for iterating through database objects (since you can use a common interface for iterating through forms, macros, modules and reports).

If you want to modify forms and reports created on the fly, and want to store them in the same variable, you're limited to the `Object` type (or `Variant`, but that's even less specific).

Comment: Thanks. So based on that description, I'd say AccessObject is a sort of stub; a metaobject that just has info about other objects, but not good for much else. Kind of like a small set of offices with a lobby and office doors that open to brick walls, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the ability to use intellisense (formally known as picklist) in MS Access Module using VBA to reference the controls of any existing object (Table, Query, Form, Report).

I used to heavily rely on 'Me' and found it to be quite convenient and useful, but never liked its limitations.

The following solution is what I have developed, and implemented across multiple applications that I've worked on, as an alternative to 'Me'.

```
'Function Declaration to use 'this.':
Dim this As Form_myFormName
Set this = Mee

'Function Declaration to use 'Mee.':
Dim Mee As Form_myFormName
Set Mee = this

'Function Code Module:

Public Property Get Mee() As Object
On Error Resume Next
Dim dbApp As ezGetElementBy
Set dbApp = New ezGetElementBy
  Set Mee = dbApp.obj
End Property

Public Property Get this() As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set this = Mee
End Property


'Class Module: ezGetElementBy

Public Function obj() As Object
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim APP_OBJECT_NAME As String
Dim APP_OBJECT_TYPE As Integer
Dim dbObjectDesc As Variant

 APP_OBJECT_NAME = Application.CurrentObjectName
 APP_OBJECT_TYPE = Application.CurrentObjectType dbObjectDesc = Array("Table", "Query", "Form", "Report", "Macro", "Module")

  AsObjectType = IIf( _
    APP_OBJECT_TYPE = 2 Or APP_OBJECT_TYPE = 3, _
    dbObjectDesc(APP_OBJECT_TYPE), Object _
  )

  Select Case APP_OBJECT_TYPE
    Case 0 ' "Table"
      Set obj = Screen.ActiveDatasheet
    Case 1 ' "Query"
      Set obj = Screen.ActiveDatasheet
    Case 2 ' "Form"
      Set obj = Forms(APP_OBJECT_NAME)
    Case 3 ' "Report"
      Set obj = Reports(APP_OBJECT_NAME)
    Case Else
  End Select

Exit Function
ErrHandler:
On Error Resume Next

  Select Case APP_OBJECT_TYPE
    Case 0 ' "Table"
APP_OBJECT_NAME=Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Name
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable,APP_OBJECT_NAME, True

DoCmd.OpenTable APP_OBJECT_NAME, acViewNormal
Set obj = Screen.ActiveDatasheet

    Case 1 ' "Query"
APP_OBJECT_NAME=Screen.ActiveDatasheet.Name

DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery,APP_OBJECT_NAME, True

DoCmd.OpenQuery APP_OBJECT_NAME, acViewNormal

Set obj = Screen.ActiveDatasheet

    Case 2 ' "Form"
APP_OBJECT_NAME =Screen.ActiveForm.Name
DoCmd.SelectObject acForm,APP_OBJECT_NAME, True

DoCmd.OpenForm APP_OBJECT_NAME, acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal

Set obj = Screen.ActiveForm

    Case 3 ' "Report"
APP_OBJECT_NAME=Screen.ActiveReport.Name

DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, APP_OBJECT_NAME, True

DoCmd.OpenReport APP_OBJECT_NAME, acNormal, , , acWindowNormal
Set obj = Screen.ActiveReport

Case Else
End Select
Exit Function
End Function
```